# Is there another approach or io.swagger annotation that hides fields like how @ApiModelProperty does to hide fields of a custom Object?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger

I would like to hide for example the `id` field but NOT by annotating the field itself using `@ApiModelProperty` but at the `ParameterMapper` object level. That is, annotating `ParameterMapper`, since this object is used in multiple places and I am not showing the same fields in all place of the swagger doc.

[image]